# InnerHTML + find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching and trying different codes, but I don't came up to a solution.

This script i'm trying to create do this:

1. When the user clicks inside a div with class="Box". The program will save in a variable the content of the Box.

   ```
   var boxContent = $(this).parents('.Box')[0].innerHTML;
   ```

So, the value of the variable **boxContent** now (acording to my html output will be) returns the hole div that the user clicked:

```
    <div class="Box">
       <div class="URL_ID">
           <span>http://test.com</span>
           <span id="ID">3232434</span>
       </div>
       <div class="info">
            <a href="#"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="secondLink">
            <a href="#"></a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Now what i'd like to take is the div  to process later and do an append in a table. So i tried to use find(), but doesn't work...

```
    var url = boxContent.find('.BoxSongUrl');
```

What can i do??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no `BoxSongUrl` in your html

Comment: `innerHTML` returns a string which doesn't have `find` method!

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but for `innerHTML` use the jQuery `.html()` method. e.g. `$(this).parents('.Box').html()`. You only need to use the DOM element for outerHTML.

Comment: If you only want the first element returned by jQuery you can use `.first()` instead of `[0]`.  Not sure if it really matters though.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

> So, the value of the variable boxContent now (acording to my html output will be) returns the hole div that the user clicked:

Is not true. `innerHTML` returns a string of the markup html inside the element. To use the Jquery's `.find()` method, you have to actually select the Jquery object:

```
var url = $(this).parents('.Box').find('.BoxSongUrl');
```

Comment: -1 It's clear the OP knows how to do this all in one line.  You seem to have missed the question:  "Now what i'd like to take is the div to process later ... but doesn't work".

Comment: I'm sorry @PrestonS but **you** are missing the point! You don't have to clone a div (as you suggested), or store its html string markup (as the OP was trying). A Jquery object is a reference to the actual DOM element, that can be naviagated, manipulated and searched... In my answer, storing the `find` result is enough, since you can call the parent `.Box` at any time later!

Comment: And what if the dom element has changed by the time it would be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone` to retain a copy of the first '.Box' element at the time the query is run.

```
var boxContent = $(this).parents('.Box').first().clone();
```

Then, you can use the find method on `boxContent`

```
var url = boxContent.find('.BoxSongUrl');
```

EDIT:

If you would rather not clone the whole jQuery object you would save the html and re-parse it before calling find.

```
var boxContent = $(this).parents('.Box').first().html();
```

Then, re-parse the HTML into a jQuery object:

```
var url = $(boxContent).find('.BoxSongUrl');
```

Comment: Why would he do that??? Create a whole copy of the div, just to perform a search?

Comment: @LcSalazar Don't ask me, the question says the OP wants to save the contents and search them later.  Presumably because the contents will have changed by the time the future code executes.  This is how you would do that.